# Ajax call not working when sending data to another page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my code:

```
<div class="category" id="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>   </div>


$(".category").click(function(){

             var categ = $(this).attr('id');
                              alert(categ);


    ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=238',
  data:'cat='+categ,
  success:function(data) {
    if(data) {  


    } else { // DO SOMETHING 
  }
       }
});       

    });
```

and the code behind the page which is receiving the posted data (http://myweb.com//rel_notes/?page_id=238) is here:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cat']))
{
$cat_id = $_POST['cat'];
echo "<script>alert('$cat_id')</script>";
}
else
$cat_id = NULL;
?>
```

**Problem:** It didn't get the value in $cat_id. I tried changing $_POST to $_GET but that didn't work too. So kindly help me where am i missing something?

Comment: Is it `ajax({...})` or `$.ajax({...})`?? Typo I guess!!

Comment: ops my mistake but still didn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good way dude.
None can make alert on server side.

You are doing alert code on the server side.

Just replace

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cat']))
{
$cat_id = $_POST['cat'];
echo "<script>alert('$cat_id')</script>";
}
else $cat_id = NULL;
?>
```

by

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cat']))
{
    echo $cat_id = $_POST['cat'];

}
else {
    echo $cat_id = "";
}
?>
```

and alert the code like

```
$(".category").click(function(){
    var categ = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(categ);

    ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=238',
      data:'cat='+categ,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data != "") {  
          alert(data);
        }else { // DO SOMETHING 

         }
       }
    });       

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  data: {cat: categ},
  url:'http://myweb.com//rel_notes/?page_id=238',
  error: function() {
         alert("Data Error");
    },
  success:function(data) {
     if(data) {  
    } else { 
    }
}
```

});